# Rollback in interlinked Spring transactions context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations, rollback

I would like to drop data from my db and inject new one, but if injection fails I would like to rollback to my old data.

I'm using Spring with annotations :

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class, value="manager")
public void run(Source input) {
    delete();
    injectData from input
    injectData from input
}
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, value="manager")
public void delete(){
    deleteDataListA()
    deleteDataListB()
}
```

The problem is if I toggle a breakpoint after delete() and check my DB, nothing has been deleted yet, so my injections fail

Have you got any solution ?

Comment: Is both `run` and `delete` in the same bean?

Comment: yes they are in same bean

Comment: Have you gotten an error you can share during the _insertions_ ?  Can you share how you're deleting and inserting the data?  A hibernate session should be more than capable of removing and inserting new data and coordinating with your database.

Comment: To add to my prior comment, adding a breakpoint immediately after the delete would _not_ reflect any database changes as of that time.  The changes you do with Hibernate are queued as actions and are flushed to the database at specific points in a transaction's life cycle such as before a query, when you call flush, or when the transaction commits.